# How To Copy Folder From Data To Sdcard via SU [root] eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, root

How To Copy Folder From Data To Sdcard via SU [root] eclipse android

i am making a app that copy data from /data/data/ folder

i am using this code

```
mainbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            try {

                Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                 DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
                 DataOutputStream os1 = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

                 if (null != os )
                 {
                    os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.example.app \n");
                    os.flush();
                    txtlog.setText("Changing Permission");
                 }
                 if (null != os1 )
                 {
                    os.writeBytes("mv /data/data/com.example.app  /sdcard/.myfolder \n");
                    os.flush();
                    txtlog.setText("Geting Your App Data");
                 }

            }

            catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Changing Folder Permission is working good but copying folder is not working.

i also use this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

still not working... help me please. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i solve it.

```
       if (null != os )
             {
                os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.example.app \n");
                os.flush();
                txtlog.setText("Changing Permission");

                os.writeBytes("cp -r /data/data/com.example.app  /sdcard/.myfolder \n");
                os.flush();
                txtlog.setText("Geting Your App Data");
             }
```